# Object are invisible in the 3d viewport, I get only a yellow outline

Tags: objects, import, eevee-render-engine

The cube is invisible but I can select it, this happens with most of the meshes I import.

This recently started happening 2 days ago. I tried my best to research this problem but i just can't find any solution for it.

I reinstalled blender multiple times and it just kept doing the same thing.

[image]

Also this happens in rendering view (Eevee)

Every time I zoom out, the little cube inside gets smaller, why?
[image]

I'm using version 2.83.1, this happened at 2.81 I think.

Edit: Heres the project file thing [image]

i hope i did it right, im pretty new :')

edit 2022: i found this post again. Got a new pc last year. My drivers at the time were shitty so mostly this problem was on my end aha. Sorry for the stupid question i asked.

Comment: This looks like a GPU problem or error. Can you upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so that more people can try and reproduce your issue? Check your video card drivers as well.

Comment: I've uploaded the file

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184763

Comment: Issue doesn't happen on my end, everything is normal here. I would try updating your GPU drivers. Are you on NVIDIA or AMD?

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 7480D